# Over-riding alert() with iframe src

Tags: javascript, iframe, overriding

**Here's a sample code:**

**HTML**

```
<script> alert('This is alert!') </script>
```

**JS**

```
window.alert = function(data)  //alert() over-riding
{
     console.log("Alert over-ridden");
}
```

**Issue:**

**HTML**

```
<iframe src=javascript:alert('Iframealert')>
```

**JS**

```
window.alert = function(data)  //alert() over-riding
{
   console.log("Alert over-ridden"); //This doesn't execute - I mean, this over-ride function is not called when the above iframe alert is executed
}
```

I knew iframe in another document is not applicable for parent over-riding (due to same domain policy), but, the src JS execution happens only in the parent.

So, how do I over-ride alert() which is applicable to above iframe tag?

**Update 1:**

The HTML code is static, and I cannot make any modifications to it. I can only write some JS and append to the HTML.

Is there any way to over-ride the alert() of nested browsing window?

Comment: This is actually quite an interesting question.  I think the answer must lie somewhere in [the rules for "navigating" to a `javascript:` url](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigate) (see step 14) - and the context in which it executes the dynamically created script element, which must be different to the main context in some fashion.

Comment: FWIW, [here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3y5yzke/) to reproduce the issue.  I've made it set the `src` attribute dynamically so it's unequivocal that `window.alert` has been overridden by the time that runs.

Comment: Your JS fiddle was useful, though, I need to over-ride the iframe, which ID is unknown, and injected by a [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacker.

Comment: That changes the scope of the question somewhat - this probably isn't the right way to protect yourself against XSS.

Comment: Yes, still I'm not trying to protect my code from XSS. Just, I need to over-ride that for experimentation.

Answer (score 4):

Nice question!  The answer starts by looking at the rules for what happens when the `src` attribute is evaluated.

When this happens, the spec follows a [number of steps during navigation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigate).  We end up step 14, which pertains to `javascript:` schemes.

Within that step, there are a series of sub-steps, one of which is:

> Create a script, using *script source* as the script source, *address* as the script source URL, JavaScript as the scripting language, and the script settings object of the `Window` object of the active document of the browsing context being navigated.

The important thing here is *"the Window object of the active document of the browsing context being navigated"*.  Because you're navigating an `<iframe>`, you're actually dealing with a *Nested Browsing Context*, which has it's own `window`, so having overridden the parent `window.alert` makes no difference.

You can, however, override the `alert` of the inner window:

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.alert = function(msg) {
    console.log('Overridden iframe: ' + msg);
}
```

This will only work for the `javascript:` scheme url presented to the `src` attribute, as at the time this code executes we were simply trying to get the address of the page to navigate the `<iframe>` to.  When navigation actually occurs, a new Document object with it's own `window` is created in step 23 of the navigation steps, at which point you lose your overridden `alert`.

This also relies on setting the `src` attribute using JavaScript *after* you've overridden the `alert`, you can't use an inline `src` attribute on the element as the element needs to be in the page to get hold of it and it's `contentWindow`, and putting it in the page means the `src` will get evaluated.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/runn7fku/2/) demonstrating the overriding of the `alert` within the `<iframe>`'s `src` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, the iframe element is injected into the HTML without any ID by a [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacker (not by developer). How to write my JS over-ride in such case?

Comment: @unix_root There are other ways to get hold of the iframe, but you'd need to prevent the src being present until you have overridden the `alert`, as mentioned in my answer.  That sounds like content for a different question really.

Comment: Oh. But, is there any way where I could catch up the iframe element without knowing the ID? Something similar like catching the iframe window directly?

Comment: Why this piece of code loaded in browser address bar, doesn't give me a console message in Chrome 52 x64? `data:text/html, <iframe id="root" src="javascript:alert(1)"> </iframe> <script> document.getElementById("root").contentWindow.alert = function() {console.log('overridden')} </script>`

Comment: @unix_root Comments aren't the place to ask brand new questions.  If you have a new question, ask a new question.  Link back to this one if it adds relevant context.

Comment: But, this is the same code which you've mentioned in the answer. Thought it would look like a duplicate question if I post it new. That's why asked here.